# Weird behavior in Scala

Tags: scala

How to justify below codes in Scala ? Can someone explain why does it return True in Example 3 and  False in first two examples ?

Example 1:

```
scala> val f1 = 5.2
val f1: Double = 5.2

scala> val f2 = 5.2F
val f2: Float = 5.2

scala> f1==f2
val res8: Boolean = false
```

Example 2:

```
scala> val f1 = 5.24
val f1: Double = 5.24

scala> val f2 = 5.24F
val f2: Float = 5.24

scala> f1==f2
val res9: Boolean = false
```

Example 3:

```
scala> val f1 = 5.25
val f1: Double = 5.25

scala> val f2 = 5.25F
val f2: Float = 5.25

scala> f1==f2
val res10: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Floating-point equality is tricky, especially if you mix different precessions. I would, use the same precision on both sides, and check for an error; e.g. `Math.abs(f1 - f2) < 0.001D`

Comment: In general you don't compare equality of floating numbers in most languages.

Comment: JIC you are really-really interested - [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Why it is tricky? I think it is very commonly in C-like languages: float can be not equals to int or to double, double can be not equals to int and so on. Tricky -- it is JavaScript, where `parseInt(0.0000005) == 5`

Answer (score 9):

Nothing to do with Scala, but most decimal factions cannot be accurately represented as binary floating point numbers. For those numbers, the `Float` value will be different from the `Double` value so `==` will return `false`.

In this case `5.25` does have an accurate binary floating point value (`101.01`) so both the `Float` and the `Double` are the same.